# How to Call a Specific Nested Function from Several

Tags: javascript, function, nested-function

I have a function called `kasaScenes` and specific nested 'scene' functions that perform a POST depending on which 'scene' I need to activate. (ex: `sceneTooCold`, `sceneTooHot`, etc). So later on down the process, the temperature of a sensor is compared to a threshold and if it meets the specific criteria (ex: if sensor.temperature is <= 70 then activate the 'sceneTooCold' function from kasaScenes. How would I perform that job from the below code snippet?

```
function kasaScenes() {

  function sceneTooCold() {
    post_content_gAC = '{"method":"passthrough","params":{"deviceId":"' + gACID + '","requestData":"{\\"system\\":{\\"set_relay_state\\":{\\"state\\":' + stateOff + '}}}","token":"' + kasa_token + '"}}';
    post_content_gExhaust = '{"method":"passthrough","params":{"deviceId":"' + gExhaustID + '","requestData":"{\\"system\\":{\\"set_relay_state\\":{\\"state\\":' + stateOff + '}}}","token":"' + kasa_token + '"}}';
    post_content_gFans = '{"method":"passthrough","params":{"deviceId":"' + gFansID + '","requestData":"{\\"system\\":{\\"set_relay_state\\":{\\"state\\":' + stateOn + '}}}","token":"' + kasa_token + '"}}';
    post_content_gHeater = '{"method":"passthrough","params":{"deviceId":"' + gHeaterID + '","requestData":"{\\"system\\":{\\"set_relay_state\\":{\\"state\\":' + stateOn + '}}}","token":"' + kasa_token + '"}}';
    post_content_gCeiling = '{"method":"passthrough","params":{"deviceId":"' + gCeilingID + '","requestData":"{\\"system\\":{\\"set_relay_state\\":{\\"state\\":' + stateOn + '}}}","token":"' + kasa_token + '"}}';
    //<~POST Return~>
    returnValue_gAC = KumoApp.httpCallExternal(post_url, "POST", post_content_gAC);
    returnValue_gExhaust = KumoApp.httpCallExternal(post_url, "POST", post_content_gExhaust);
    returnValue_gFans = KumoApp.httpCallExternal(post_url, "POST", post_content_gFans);
    returnValue_gHeater = KumoApp.httpCallExternal(post_url, "POST", post_content_gHeater);
    returnValue_gCeiling = KumoApp.httpCallExternal(post_url, "POST", post_content_gCeiling);

  }

  function sceneTooHot() {
    post_content_gAC = '{"method":"passthrough","params":{"deviceId":"' + gACID + '","requestData":"{\\"system\\":{\\"set_relay_state\\":{\\"state\\":' + stateOn + '}}}","token":"' + kasa_token + '"}}';
    post_content_gExhaust = '{"method":"passthrough","params":{"deviceId":"' + gExhaustID + '","requestData":"{\\"system\\":{\\"set_relay_state\\":{\\"state\\":' + stateOn + '}}}","token":"' + kasa_token + '"}}';
    post_content_gFans = '{"method":"passthrough","params":{"deviceId":"' + gFansID + '","requestData":"{\\"system\\":{\\"set_relay_state\\":{\\"state\\":' + stateOn + '}}}","token":"' + kasa_token + '"}}';
    post_content_gHeater = '{"method":"passthrough","params":{"deviceId":"' + gHeaterID + '","requestData":"{\\"system\\":{\\"set_relay_state\\":{\\"state\\":' + stateOff + '}}}","token":"' + kasa_token + '"}}';
    post_content_gCeiling = '{"method":"passthrough","params":{"deviceId":"' + gCeilingID + '","requestData":"{\\"system\\":{\\"set_relay_state\\":{\\"state\\":' + stateOn + '}}}","token":"' + kasa_token + '"}}';
    //<~POST Return~>
    returnValue_gAC = KumoApp.httpCallExternal(post_url, "POST", post_content_gAC);
    returnValue_gExhaust = KumoApp.httpCallExternal(post_url, "POST", post_content_gExhaust);
    returnValue_gFans = KumoApp.httpCallExternal(post_url, "POST", post_content_gFans);
    returnValue_gHeater = KumoApp.httpCallExternal(post_url, "POST", post_content_gHeater);
    returnValue_gCeiling = KumoApp.httpCallExternal(post_url, "POST", post_content_gCeiling);

  }

  function sceneNormalTemp() {
    post_content_gCeiling = '{"method":"passthrough","params":{"deviceId":"' + gCeilingID + '","requestData":"{\\"system\\":{\\"set_relay_state\\":{\\"state\\":' + stateOff + '}}}","token":"' + kasa_token + '"}}';
    post_content_gExhaust = '{"method":"passthrough","params":{"deviceId":"' + gExhaustID + '","requestData":"{\\"system\\":{\\"set_relay_state\\":{\\"state\\":' + stateOff + '}}}","token":"' + kasa_token + '"}}';
    post_content_gFans = '{"method":"passthrough","params":{"deviceId":"' + gFansID + '","requestData":"{\\"system\\":{\\"set_relay_state\\":{\\"state\\":' + stateOn + '}}}","token":"' + kasa_token + '"}}';
    post_content_gHeater = '{"method":"passthrough","params":{"deviceId":"' + gHeaterID + '","requestData":"{\\"system\\":{\\"set_relay_state\\":{\\"state\\":' + stateOff + '}}}","token":"' + kasa_token + '"}}';
    //<~POST Return~>
    returnValue_gAC = KumoApp.httpCallExternal(post_url, "POST", post_content_gAC);
    returnValue_gExhaust = KumoApp.httpCallExternal(post_url, "POST", post_content_gExhaust);
    returnValue_gFans = KumoApp.httpCallExternal(post_url, "POST", post_content_gFans);
    returnValue_gHeater = KumoApp.httpCallExternal(post_url, "POST", post_content_gHeater);

  }

  function sceneTooWet() {
    post_content_gCeiling = '{"method":"passthrough","params":{"deviceId":"' + gCeilingID + '","requestData":"{\\"system\\":{\\"set_relay_state\\":{\\"state\\":' + stateOn + '}}}","token":"' + kasa_token + '"}}';
    post_content_gExhaust = '{"method":"passthrough","params":{"deviceId":"' + gExhaustID + '","requestData":"{\\"system\\":{\\"set_relay_state\\":{\\"state\\":' + stateOn + '}}}","token":"' + kasa_token + '"}}';
    post_content_gFans = '{"method":"passthrough","params":{"deviceId":"' + gFansID + '","requestData":"{\\"system\\":{\\"set_relay_state\\":{\\"state\\":' + stateOn + '}}}","token":"' + kasa_token + '"}}';
    post_content_gDehumidifier = '{"method":"passthrough","params":{"deviceId":"' + gDehumidifierID + '","requestData":"{\\"system\\":{\\"set_relay_state\\":{\\"state\\":' + stateOn + '}}}","token":"' + kasa_token + '"}}';
    post_content_gHumidifier = '{"method":"passthrough","params":{"deviceId":"' + gHumidifierID + '","requestData":"{\\"system\\":{\\"set_relay_state\\":{\\"state\\":' + stateOff + '}}}","token":"' + kasa_token + '"}}';
    //<~POST Return~>
    returnValue_gCeiling = KumoApp.httpCallExternal(post_url, "POST", post_content_gCeiling);
    returnValue_gExhaust = KumoApp.httpCallExternal(post_url, "POST", post_content_gExhaust);
    returnValue_gFans = KumoApp.httpCallExternal(post_url, "POST", post_content_gFans);
    returnValue_gDehumidifier = KumoApp.httpCallExternal(post_url, "POST", post_content_gDehumidifier);
    returnValue_gHumidifier = KumoApp.httpCallExternal(post_url, "POST", post_content_gHumidifier);

  }
}
```

Comment: You are not returning anything from the parent function, so this is simply not possible right now. Either convert the parent function to a object with key/value pairs with keys sceneTooCold, sceneTooHot etc and thier values as corresponding functions or create `kasaScenes` as a class instead and the respective functions as its methods.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What do you need other than `if (sensor.temperature < 70) { sceneTooCol(); } else if (sensor.temperature > 100) { sceneTooHot(); } else { sceneNormalTemp(); }`

Comment: @rahulpsd18 That makes sense. I'm still fairly new at js so I didn't know I needed something returned. I actually don't need any values returned but rather just for that specific part (what I thought should be a function) to run the POST. Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: @Barmar So placing this elsewhere outside of the outer function will work?  I was trying that but kept getting "TypeError: 'sceneTooDry()' is not a function".

Comment: No, it should be inside the outer function.

Comment: When you call `kasaScenes()` it will then call the appropriate inner functions.

Comment: @Barmar That definitely gave me what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got to the answer by using the suggestion @Barmar made. I don't see where I can mark this answered.

I called the inner functions from inside the outer function as he had suggested.